# Flask not finding stylesheet or other static files

Tags: flask

I cannot get my Flask application to find my stylesheets or other files.  Here is my file structure:

[image: File Structure]

Then, in my index.html, which the template is rendering for, I have this code for, for example, my style.css file.

```html
 <!-- Personal CSS -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{% url_for('static', filename=styles/style.css') %}">
```

Finally, the terminal says that the GET Html requests fails with a 404.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't get confused with Django.

Flask's template engine, Jinja2, uses double braces for the `url_for` function:

Also the path you provide is a string so should be in quotes:

```
{{ url_for('static', filename='styles/style.css') }}
```